# Redirect IP to host name in NGINX

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, nginx, proxy, ip

I want to redirect each IP address of my web site to the host name of that web site using rewrite directive and than access the web site using **proxy_pass** directive in NGINX like this

```
 proxy_pass http://host/name ;
```

Using NGINX as a proxy works for but i couldn't change my script to rewrite addresses and proxy my request at the same time. I tried to use Rewrite directive but i can't find the right syntax for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using rewrite directive to change host will cause a redirection. It means client needs to post another request with new host, and then, you can proxy_pass this request. In this case, the URL in client (for example, browser) will change, like '`http://*.*.*.*:port/uri?request_string`' -> '`http://host/uri?request_string`'.

Usually, we use rewrite directive to change the URI of the request which will be proxy_passed. If you want to change the host, using `proxy_set_header`. An example:

```
location ~* "^/maishenme/(knowse|knowdetail|iget|ilist|initem|i?compare)(.*)?$" {
        rewrite "^/maishenme/(.*)?$" /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://***.xxx.com;
        proxy_set_header Host "internal.xxx.com";
        break;
}
```

And in this case, from the client side, the url do not change, but for the backend server, you can print the host field and see it changed to "internal.xxx.com"

Comment: Can you please explain more this code for me and how can i test it with a real IP and host name of a website

Comment: If you can accept a 301 or 302 redirection, using "redirect" directive  and then proxy_pass.If you want to change the host field in proxy_pass, you can use proxy_set_header to replace it. Read the manual and try more.